# How can my Cocoa app be notified when the user empties the trash?

Tags: cocoa, notifications, recycle-bin

My app puts some files in the trash, but also implements undo to pull them back out again. I need to know if the user empties the trash so I can empty my undo stack.

Do I need to monitor file system events to achieve this, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to end up watching ~/.Trash, but there *is* a notification posted when the trash is emptied.  Its name is `"com.apple.carbon.core.DirectoryNotification"` (which is also posted at other times), but it doesn't seem to have anything in the userInfo.  However, it does have a string as the object, so that might contain some relevant information.  My quick tests seem to indicate that it doesn't.  (It looks like a string that's something like `"FNObject 555279-101"`)

Comment: Thanks. I found an example of using this at https://github.com/erica/GrabUpper/blob/master/grabupper.m. Once I know that a change is possible I can check the trash for empty and respond appropriately.

Comment: Note also that the trash is not only at `~/.Trash`; a file on an external drive is moved to `/path/to/mountpoint/Trashes/uid/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UKKQueue](http://www.zathras.de/programming/cocoa/UKKQueue.zip/UKKQueue/) to watch file change (empty thrash) notifications:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UKKQueue

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `FNSubscribe` or `FNSubscribeByPath`.  The notification won't tell you exactly what happened, just that something happened to the directory you subscribed to.